# pip fails: _in_process.py missing (but _in_process.pyc is present)

Tags: python, linux, pip

TL;DR: What do I need to do in order to install the python `spidev` on my single-board linux machine?

On a semi-custom Linux system:

```
# uname -a
Linux sama7 5.15.32-linux4microchip-2022.04 #1 Thu Jun 9 10:03:39 CEST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to `pip install spidev`, but I get this error:

```
# pip install spidev --user
Collecting spidev
  Using cached spidev-3.6.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py'
```

What's interesting is that `_in_process.pyc` exists in that directory, but not `_in_process.py`:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/
total 16
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           881 Jun  9  2022 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          9775 Jun  9  2022 _in_process.pyc
```

Only slightly less interesting is I cannot find the cached `spidev-3.6*` anywhere on the system:

```
# find / -name "spidev-3.6.*"
#
```

### Update

I just noticed there *is* a `_in_process.py` present, but in another directory:

```
# find / -name "_in_process.*"
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.pyc
```

Comment: `site-packages/pip` I think your pip installation is not ok. Try reinstaling pip. Try `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @KamilCuk Upgrading `pip` worked, mostly.  Now it's failing to build due to a lack of `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`, but I believe that's unrelated.